# How to make PuTTY display tabs within a file instead of changing them to spaces?

Tags: unix, putty

I have a problem with PuTTY: whenever I SSH into a UNIX computer using PuTTY on my Windows PC and I try to browse files, everything looks fine, but my tab delimited files appear to have spaces instead of tabs!

For example, when I open a tab delimited file in `vim` and use my arrow keys to transverse the cursor between columns, the cursor jumps across the tab gaps. However, when I use my mouse to highlight a portion of the text, my cursor "sees" spaces between each column. So, when I copy the text to my clipboard, all tabs have been replaced with stretches of spaces.

Does anyone know how to stop this behavior? I want PuTTY to properly display tabs instead of spaces, and more importantly, I want to be able to capture text from my files in UNIX to my clipboard while preserving their tabs!

Comment: I think this is a wishlist item for Putty: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/paste-fidelity.html

Comment: Does anyone have a work-around? I really need to be able to copy text with tabs from my shell while SSHing into my server. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I use is to do

`cat -t file.txt`

What that does is display tabs as `^I`. I copy and paste from Putty to my Windows text editor. Then replace all the `^I` with tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Use "set list" in your .vimrc. If you don't like the ^I default, use "set listchars". See [the description at the vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces#Using_the_list_and_listchars_options).